# Prove that $6 - \sqrt{2}$ is Irrational by contradiction

Tags: elementary-number-theory, radicals, rationality-testing

What is a Proof by Contradiction, and how to prove by contradiction that $6 - \sqrt{2}$ is an irrational number?

Comment: Suppose that $6-\sqrt 2$ is rational.  Then...

Comment: then what should I do...

Comment: $HussainHalai What have you tried?  This is not that difficult of a problem.  Edit in how far you've gotten and we'll see if we can help get you past wherever you're stuck.

Comment: Hint: if $r$ is rational, then $6-r$ is rational.

Comment: What if I had 6 - 2 ^(1/7) would I use the same method...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A proof by contradiction is assuming something then building on it and finding that it leads to contradiction, concluding that the assumed statement is false.

Assume $x=6-\sqrt{2}=\frac{p}{q}$

$x^2=8-12\sqrt{2}=\frac{p^2}{q^2}$

$8q^2=p^2+12\sqrt{2}q^2$

$8q^2-p^2=12\sqrt{2}q^2$

$8q^2-p^2$ is rational, and $q^2$ is rational, thus $12\sqrt{2}$ is rational.

However, we know that that is not true, and thus, $6-\sqrt{2}$ is irrational.

Comment: Needlessly complicated! If $6-\sqrt 2 = \frac{p}{q}$, then $\sqrt 2 = 6 - \frac{p}{q}$ would be rational.

Comment: @TonyK Now I feel retarded... I have never done such an exercise, so yeah, I made useless steps. Thanks though. :)

Answer (score 2):

If $6-\sqrt{2}$ is rational, then $\sqrt{2}$ is rational. Then just prove it for $\sqrt{2}$ which is easy.

Answer (score 0):

The method of proof by contradiction is done by assuming the negation of a given proposition is true, then finding a contradiction with that assumption, hence proving the original statement. For instance, suppose $6-\sqrt{2}$ is rational, then we can say that for $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}$ we have $$6-\sqrt{2}=\frac{a}{b}$$
where $a$ and $b$ are coprime. Now, we can do some algebra and find a contradiction.