# Prove that $3 - 2 ^ {1/7}$ is Irrational

Tags: elementary-number-theory, radicals, rationality-testing

How to prove that $3 - 2 ^ {1/7}$ is irrational?

If I do

$$\frac p q = 3 - 2 ^ {1/7}$$

$$2 ^ {1/7} = 3 - \frac p q $$

Hint needed

Should I multiply by $7$ times??

Comment: Yes, multiply it by itself seven times. But don't worry about the right hand side. All it matters is that $3-p/q$ is also of the form $m/n$, (rational).

Comment: Show first that $\sqrt[7]{2}$ is irrational. A similar proof to the one for the irrationality of $\sqrt{2}$ works.

Comment: $3 - \dfrac p q = \dfrac{3q}q - \dfrac p q = \dfrac{3q-p}q = \dfrac m n$, so you have $2^{1/7}=\dfrac m n$. The "3" is just clutter, so get rid of it that way.  ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Should I prove like it that Sum of Irrational num and Rational num is Irrational...

Comment: Nice @MichaelHardy a good explanation...

Comment: You just [asked a question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1202980/1508) that hinged on the obvious fact that if $r$ is irrational, then $6-r$ is irrational. Why are you repeating yourself here?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Suppose $3-2^{1/7}=\frac{m}{n},$ for some $m,n\in\Bbb Z,$ $n\neq0.$ Then $(3n-m)^7=n^7+n^7,$ which contradicts Fermat's Last Theorem!.

Comment: I really like this answer.

Comment: I approve this Answer...

Comment: Technically correct, but perhaps a tiny bit of overkill!

Comment: Do Explain @GeoffRobinson I am just curious...

Comment: Well, Fermat's Last Theorem requires very deep number theory and algebraic geometry. The uniqueness of prime factorization is a much simpler and more direct tool.

Comment: Definitely the hard way!

Comment: Amazing and a very beautiful answer

Comment: @HussainHalai Fermat's Last Theorem was unsolved for 300 years. When it was finally proven, in 1995, the proof was hundreds of pages long. This is _definitely_ overkill!

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $3-2^{1/7}$ is rational,Hence $2^{1/7}=3-(3-2^{1/7})$ is rational.we will prove that $2^{1/7}$ is irrational.

**Direct Proof**:Just use the rational root test on the polynomial equation $x^7-2=0$ (note that $\sqrt[7]{2}$ is a solution to this equation).  If this equation were to have a rational root $\frac{a}{b}$ with gcd$(a,b)=1$ (with $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $b\not=0$), then $b\vert 1$ and $a\vert 2$.  Thus, $\frac{a}{b}\in\{\pm 1,\pm 2\}$.  However, none of $\pm 1,\pm 2$ are solutions of $x^7-2=0$.  Therefore the equation $x^7-2=0$ has no rational solutions and $\sqrt[7]{2}$ is irrational.Hence We are done!

Alternatively, suppose we have $\sqrt[7]{2}=\frac{a}{b}$ for some $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}$, $b\not=0$, and $\gcd(a,b)=1$.  Then, rearranging and cubing, we have $2b^7=a^7$.  Therefore $a^7$ is even....what does that say about $a$?  What, in turn, does that say about $b$?  It's really not that different from the classic proof that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational.

Comment: You also need to assume $\,\gcd(a,b)=1\,$ to apply the Rational Root Test. Thankfully, the proof is infinitely simpler than that for FLT sledgehammer used elsewhere.

Comment: Fixed Now !Thank You @BillDubuque

Answer (score 0):

You can safely ignore the term $3$.

Let $p^7=2q^7$, with $p$ and $q$ relative primes. Then $p^7$ is even, so that $p$ is even, so that $q^7$ is a multiple of $2^6$ so that $q$ is even, a contradiction.